# Bug in the new editing system

Tags: bug

I've noticed that, when you click 'edit' on a post, there's now a drop-down list of the previous revisions of the post.  But there are a couple of bugs.

If the title of an edit overflows the box

[image]

then there is no way to see the full text of the edit title.

If I view this revision the usual way (clicking on the 'edited at xxx by xxx' link on the original post), the full text of this edit title is

```
Shifted focus to Olbers' paradox in title and mention in the text, to make more distinct from the (non-)dupicates
```

The end of this sentence should be accessible in some way from the 'edit' interface as well.

In addition, clicking on the items in the list does nothing - you'd expect to be able to revert to a specific edit by clicking on it in the list, but nothing happens if you do that.

Comment: This isn't new, this is just the full editor that was used before the inline editor was introduced, and is still used if your browser doesn't support the inline editor, you don't have full editing privileges or you navigate to the editing URL yourself.